# How do you get to the slope intercept formula from this linear function?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to re-learn calculus - it's been years since I've been in school. I started reading some lessons online and am stuck on this page: http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/calculus_beginners/chapter03/section02.html

They state a linear function as:

$$f(x)=f(a){\frac{x-b}{a-b}+f(b)\frac{x-a}{b-a}}$$

and then state that you can also express this function as:

$$f(x)={\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}x+\frac{b\cdot f(a)-a\cdot f(b)}{b-a}}$$
$$f(x)=mx+c$$

Now, I am familiar with $f(x)=mx+c$ (or $y=mx+b$ as I learned it in school), but I have no idea how you get from the first function displayed to the second function and then on to the final slope intercept form.

I know this is a very low-level question for this site, but if someone could explain the relation I would be very thankful. I've searched online and can't find anywhere that expresses the linear function in the first form used here.

Answer (score 2):

It's just (a lot of) algebra:

\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= f(a) \frac{x-b}{a-b} + f(b) \frac{x-a}{b-a} \\
&= f(a) \frac{x-b}{a-b} - f(b) \frac{x-a}{a-b} \text{, by negating num and denom of 2nd term}\\
&= \frac{ f(a)(x-b) - f(b) (x-a)}{a-b} \text{, by combining over common denom.}\\
&= \frac{ xf(a) - bf(a) - xf(b) + af(b)}{a-b} \text{, by expanding out products}\\
&= \frac{ x(f(a) - f(b))  + af(b)- bf(a)}{a-b} \text{, by reordering terms}\\
&= x\frac{ f(a) - f(b)}{a-b}  + \frac{af(b)- bf(a)}{a-b} \text{, splitting into two fracs, and factoring out an $x$}\\
\end{align}

Oh...and to get to the final form, you take $m$ to be $\frac{ f(a) - f(b)}{a-b}$, and $c$ to be $\frac{af(b)- bf(a)}{a-b}$.